# Want to show/hide div based on dropdown box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I want to have jQuery show div id='business' only if 'business use' is selected in the dropdown box.

This is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$('#purpose').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == '1');
  {
    $("#business").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#business").hide();
  }
});
});
</script>
<body>
<select id='purpose'>
<option value="0">Personal use</option>
<option value="1">Business use</option>
<option value="2">Passing on to a client</option>
</select>
<div style='display:none;' id='business'>Business Name<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
```

and the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2kGzZ/1/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Wrap the code within `$(document).ready(function(){...........});` handler , also remove the `;` after `if`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1')
      //.....................^.......
      {
        $("#business").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#business").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/v4gNL/)

Comment: Or put it at the end of the document.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing without javascript?

Answer (score 9):

The core problem is the js errors:

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function () {
    // if (this.value == '1'); { No semicolon and I used === instead of ==
    if (this.value === '1'){
        $("#business").show();
    } else {
        $("#business").hide();
    }
});
// }); remove
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/2kGzZ/3/

I had to clean up the html & js...I couldn't help myself.

HTML:

```
<select id='purpose'>
    <option value="0">Personal use</option>
    <option value="1">Business use</option>
    <option value="2">Passing on to a client</option>
</select>
<form id="business">
    <label for="business">Business Name</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#business {
  display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function () {
    if(this.value === "1"){
        $("#business").show();
    } else {
        $("#business").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to either put your code at the end of the page or wrap it in a document ready call, otherwise you're trying to execute code on elements that don't yet exist. Also, you can reduce your code to:

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function () {
    $("#business").css('display', (this.value == '1') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/24HnJ/)**

Answer (score 6):

you have error in your code `unexpected token`.use:

```
  $('#purpose').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == '1') {
    $("#business").show();
    } else {
    $("#business").hide();
   }

   });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2kGzZ/2/)**

**Update:** You can narrow down the code using `.toggle()`

```
 $('#purpose').on('change', function () {
   $("#business").toggle(this.value == '1');
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1')
      //.....................^.......
      {
           $("#business_new").hide();
        $("#business").show();
      }
      else  if ( this.value == '2')
      {
          $("#business").hide();
        $("#business_new").show();
      }
       else  
      {
        $("#business").hide();
      }
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<select id='purpose'>
<option value="0">Personal use</option>
<option value="1">Business use</option>
<option value="2">Passing on to a client</option>
</select>
<div style='display:none;' id='business'>Business Name<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
    <br/>
</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='business_new'>Business Name<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value="1254" size='20' />
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this which is working for me in my test demo

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#dropdown').change(function() 
{ 
//  var selectedValue = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
var text = $('#dropdown').val();
//alert("text");
    //Depend on Value i.e. 0 or 1 respective function gets called. 
    switch(text){
        case 'Reporting':
          // alert("hello1");
   $("#td1").hide();
            break;
        case 'Buyer':
      //alert("hello");
     $("#td1").show();   
            break;
        //etc... 
        default:
            alert("catch default");
            break;
    }
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-select-box
It's working well in my case

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Select Box</title>
<style>
    .box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 50px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #228B22; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option>Choose Color</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```