# Create two dropdown boxes from a multidimensional array in php, one for the key, another one for the item in the key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional php array as following:

```
$country = array ("India" => array("Maharashtra","Tamil Nadu","West Bengal"),
                  "USA"=> array ("New York", "California", "Florida"),
                  "Canada"=>array("Ontario", "Alberta", "Manitoba"));
```

I want to create two drop down boxes. One will have the country name. The other will have the state name, which will get populated when the first box is selected.

I have written the code for the first box:

```
echo "<select name='name'>\n";
foreach($country as $key => $item) {
    echo "\t<option>$key</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";
```

Can anyone suggest me how to create the next drop down box?

Comment: You will have to use javascript to build the second select box on change of the first select. Else, you wouldn't know what to put inside the second box without knowing what was selected in the first box.

Comment: you need to loop over $item next within the first loop.

Comment: @JoshKG i tried to loop the $item but the select box was empty.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn is correct, this is a two-part process. First you'll need to output the state arrays, either into the DOM or perhaps just into a javascript object, then use javascript to dynamically build the select options after knowing which country was selected.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn If the value was in the database, I could populate the next select box using javascript. But now, how to take the data from the array?

Comment: Check out Mikel's answer below to see how to loop a 2nd time to get the states.

Comment: Your inner loop would look something like `foreach($item as $value2){ ... }` and you would want to concatenate a variable and output it later. You could also just `json_encode` the entire array and then build the second select in js based on the selected value from the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this sample code. From my understanding you don't want to make use of a database or an additional ajax call so I populated a javascriopt cache variable object with all states

```
    <?php
$data = array("India" => array("Maharashtra", "Tamil Nadu", "West Bengal"),
    "USA" => array("New York", "California"),
    "Canada" => array("Ontario", "Alberta", "Manitoba"));
$countries = array_keys($data);
?>
<!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script>
//Store country as a javascript object
    var countries = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select[name="countries"]').change(function () {
            var country_val = $(this).val();
            if (countries[country_val]) {
                var options = '<option value = "">Select State</option>';
                for (i in countries[country_val]) {
                    var state = countries[country_val][i];
                    options += '<option value = "' + state + '">' + state + '</option>';
                }
                $('select[name="states"]').html(options);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<!--First Dropdown-->
<div class="country">
    <select name="countries">
        <?php foreach ($countries as $country): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $country; ?>"><?php echo $country ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<!--Second Dropdown-->
<div class="states">
    <select name="states">
        <option>Select State</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work. Follow step by step.

**YourPage.php**

```
<?
$country = array ("India" => array("Maharashtra","Tamil Nadu","West Bengal"),
                  "USA"=> array ("New York", "California"),
                  "Canada"=>array("Ontario", "Alberta", "Manitoba")); 
?>

<div class='country'>
    <select name="country_name" class="Country">
    <?
    foreach($country as $countryName => $states) {?>
        <option value="<? echo $countryName;?>"><?echo $countryName?></option>
    <?}?>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="State">
    <select>
        <option>Select Country</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Add this code in your **.js** file.

```
<script>
$('.Country').change(function(){
    var StateName= $('.Country').val();
    $.ajax({url:"AjaxSelectState.php?CountryName="+CountryName,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $('.State').html(result);
    }});
});
</script>
```

**AjaxSelectState.php** 
(Create this page. And, make sure if you want to change name of this page, change in `<script></script>` tag too. Both are related)

```
<?
$CountryName=$_GET['CountryName'];
$totalState=sizeof($country[$CountryName]);
?>
<select name="states_<?echo $CountryName;?>">
    <?
    for($i=0;$i<$totalState;$i++)
    {?>
    <option value="<?echo $country[$CountryName][$i];?>"><?echo $country[$CountryName][$i];?></option>
    <?}?>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
// Build country array
$country = array ("India" => array("Maharashtra","Tamil Nadu","West Bengal"),
                  "USA"=> array ("New York", "California", "Florida"),
                  "Canada"=>array("Ontario", "Alberta", "Manitoba"));   

// Output the country selection
echo '<select name="country_name" id="country_select">';
foreach($country as $countryName => $states) {
    echo '<option value="'.$countryName.'">'.$countryName.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

// Output a select for the state selection per country
foreach($country as $countryName => $states) {
    echo '<select class="state_dropdown" name="states_'.$countryName.'" style="display: none;">';
    foreach($states as $state){
        echo '<option value="'.$state.'">'.$state.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Please note that this will actually create 4 selects. This is because depending on the selection for the first < select >, you should show the appropriate second < select >

**Example Javascript:**
This JS requires jQuery be loaded on your page before this code is run.

```
// When the document has loaded...
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Find the country select and listen for a change...
    jQuery('#country_select').change(function(){
        // When this change happens, hide all state fields
        jQuery('.state_dropdown').hide();
        // Get the country the user selected
        var country = jQuery(this).val();
        // And show only the state field they need to see.
        jQuery('select[name=states_'+country+']').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Here all the states are being displayed. They are not dependent on the country box.

Comment: my suggestion to you @masonCOD is please make separate tables for country and state in database. It will solve your problem so easily. Only a suggestion. Not mandatory.

Comment: @masonCOD Yes, they are all output. As I stated in my answer, this would require you to write javascript that would hide the 4 state selects and show the appropriate one depending on the user's selection for the country dropdown. There is no way for the PHP to change the dropdown on the front-end without JS.

Comment: @masonCOD To get your started on the JS, simply add style="display:none;" to the state select elements. Then, add a jQuery .change() function on the country dropdown that shows the correct state_ dropdown depending on the selection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584752/want-to-show-hide-div-based-on-dropdown-box-selection

Comment: @MikelBitson Can you suggest me how to code the javascript so that selection of the state depends on the country selected.

Comment: I can pick out the country selected in the first box. I need to know, how to create the second box after I know the first box selection.

Comment: @masonCOD You create all of the selects at once and only show the one the user needs to fill out. I've added some JS and modified my HTML.