# Dropdown list after selecting value create new fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**EXPLAINATION**

I need achieve, that after value from dropdown list is selected It should automatically create new line below as shown in image.

**SAMPLE**

If *Option A* is selected, It should generate row number (*in this case 1*), title column with selected value's name and 2 input fields (*Date From & Date To*), after It If (for example) we select *Option C* It should generate 1 more new line, just with new row number (*in this case will be 2*)

[image: drop down list]

**CODE**

Simple dropdown list:

```
<select>
  <option value="A">Option A</option>
  <option value="B">Option B</option>
  <option value="C">Option C</option>
  <option value="D">Option D</option>
</select>
```

I don't have ideas how can I achieve It, I've tried to play with visibility, but far away from what I need...

Also selected options should be inserted to database.

**UPDATE**

The same option can't be selected twice, It can be added only 1 time. There also should appear `X` near row to remove row if clicked wrong.

Sorting of rows:

If I select C, later A and after It D It should appear in order:

```
 1. C [      ]  [      ] X
 2. A [      ]  [      ] X
 3. D [      ]  [      ] X
```

If I remove A from list It should appear:

```
 1. C [      ]  [      ] X
 2. D [      ]  [      ] X -- this row number should change.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to show/hide div based on dropdown box selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584752/want-to-show-hide-div-based-on-dropdown-box-selection)

Comment: @TimTroiano It should let select multiple values and generate row numbers for them.

Comment: So if they select A it shows dates for A and if they select B after it adds a line to show options for B?

Comment: If they select A it show text boxes for A, If after It select B it append 1 more line with text boxes for B and so on.

Comment: But If first It select B and after It select option A, It should add in 1st row B and in 2nd row A

Comment: Can I select B, A, B, C, D, A and have 6 dates based on those options or only a unique combination of 4 based on A, B, C, D?

Comment: It should add only unique rows (A B C D) and also It should have ability to remove row If selected wrong.

Comment: Use jquery, on change of the select menu, user this keyword to get the selected value and then simply append after select menu the html (only boxes and etc ). Not that hard mate...you could've searched Google easily.

Comment: @James111 thanks for suggestion, but I'm really new at JavaScript/JQuery, that's not looks so simple for me.

Comment: Could you update the question with all the details you've added/clarified in the comments? (Click the [edit] link here, or below your question's tags, to do so.) Also, you need to explain how the selected `<option>` dictates what should be shown/added. How did you want the rows to be removed/removable if they're "*selected wrong*"? Can each `<option>` be selected multiple times, or once only? If a row produced by selecting "A" is removed should option "A" be valid again? While you've asked a question "*How can I...?*" you haven't added anywhere enough detail, or demonstrated any attempts.

Comment: @DavidThomas updated my question

Comment: You really need to make an attempt to do this yourself and come back when you're stuck on a specific part of it.  As it is now, you're basically asking someone to do your whole project for you, and that's not what we're here for.

Comment: Thank you, now you need to show what you've already tried, and clearly explain where your attempted solutions went wrong, how they went wrong, what they did that you didn't want, what they didn't do that you wanted and any error messages produced in your JavaScript console (F12 in *most* browsers).

Comment: @DavidThomas I explained what went wrong on every answer's comments.

Comment: Then you misunderstand; you need to demonstrate an attempt to solve this problem yourself. And, if - or when - your own solution doesn't work *then* come back and ask questions about the problems you're facing. Critiquing other people's code is sensible, and you've provided useful details, but we're here to *help* not do your work for you. Which, I realise, may sound unhelpful but [SO] is here for enthusiasts and professionals, both of whom should have the capacity to make an attempt. If you're just now learning, this may not be the best place for you to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#select_id').change(function () {
            var szTr;
            var iRowCount = 0;

            var szSelectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();


            if ($("#table tbody tr:has(td:eq(1):contains('" + szSelectedText + "'))").length > 0) {
                alert("Duplicate!!!!")
                return;
            }
            else {
                iRowCount = $('#table tbody tr').length + 1;
                szTr = "<tr>"
                szTr = szTr + "<td>" + iRowCount + "</td>";
                szTr = szTr + "<td>" + $(this).find('option:selected').text() + "</td>"
                szTr = szTr + "<td><input type='text' class='date_from'></td>"
                szTr = szTr + "<td><input type='text' class='date_to'></td>"
                szTr = szTr + "<td class='delete'>Delete</td>"
                szTr = szTr + "</tr>"
                $('#table tbody').append(szTr)
            }

        });

        $('#table').on('click','.delete',function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            $('#btnSort').trigger('click');
        });

        function sortTable(table, order) {

            tbody = table.find('tbody');

            tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
                if (order == "asc") {
                    return $('td:eq(1)', a).text().localeCompare($('td:eq(1)', b).text());
                } else {
                    return $('td:eq(1)', b).text().localeCompare($('td:eq(1)', a).text());
                }
            }).appendTo(tbody);
        }

        $('#btnSort').click(function () {

            var iCounter = 1;

            sortTable($('#table'), "asc")

            $('#table tbody tr').each(function () {

                $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(iCounter);

                iCounter = iCounter + 1;

            });
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="select_id">
  <option value="A">Option A</option>
  <option value="B">Option B</option>
  <option value="C">Option C</option>
  <option value="D">Option D</option>
</select>

    <table id="table" >
        <thead>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>Date from</td>
    <td>Date to</td>
  </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>



        </tbody>
</table>

    <input type="button" value="Sort Table" id="btnSort"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but there I can add duplicates, It should be ability to and only 1 row per value. Also how about removing row? Something like `X` button to remove row If selected wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much, looks like better, just now after removing row It not changing row number of bottom row, check my last example in question.

Comment: Check It here http://jsfiddle.net/v4gNL/531/ , try to add B > A > C > D> A > C> B > D and It still adding duplicates, also If I add for example  `1 A > 2 B > 3 C > 4 D` and removing `3 C` from list `4 D` should came `3 D` (should decrease row number)

Comment: It's almost fine, jsut not changed already added rows number. `1 A > 2 B > 3 C > 4 D` If I remove `3 C` row, It showing `1 A > 2 B > 4 D`, but It should be `1 A > 2 B > 3 D`

Comment: Check now :)  or just uncomment the code that I commented b:)

Comment: Working ?  @infinity

Comment: Really this part about changing row number after deleting, not working

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm i didnt see your update while working on it... but Updated

https://jsfiddle.net/p76L4327/7/

Here is the html you can

```
 <body>
  <select id='options'>
    <option value="0">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">Option A</option>
    <option value="2">Option B</option>
    <option value="3">Option C</option>
    <option value="4">Option D</option>
  </select>
  <form action="">
    <div id="action2">

    </div>
    <div id='submit'>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Here is the plugin optionTest

```
   $(function() {
  $.fn.optionTest = function(opts) {
    var option = $.extend({}, $.fn.optionTest.defaults, opts);


    $(this).change(function() {
            option.holderObject=$(this);

      if (option.clearOnChange) {
        $(option.actionId).empty();
      }
      var val = $(this).val();
      if ($.fn.optionTest.isArray(val)) {
        $.fn.optionTest.parseArray(val, option);
      } else {
                var label =$(this).children("option:selected").eq(0).text();
        $.fn.optionTest.parseContent(val, option, label);
      }

      $('.' + option.removeLinkOptions.class).click(function(event) {
        $.fn.optionTest.removeRow(this, option);
        event.preventDefault();

      });
      return this;
    });
  };
  $.fn.optionTest.isArray = function(val) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Array]';
  };
  $.fn.optionTest.defaults = {
    clearOnChange: false,
    actionId: '#action',
    indexOptions: {
      class: 'row-index'
    },
    rowOptions: {
      id: 'option',
      class: 'test-css',
      tag: 'tr'
    },
    fromOptions: {
      name: 'from',
      type: 'text',
      value: 'from',
      size: 20
    },
    toOptions: {
      name: 'to',
      type: 'text',
      value: 'to',
      size: 20
    },
    removeLinkOptions: {
      class: 'removeRow',
      href: 'javascript:;'
    }
  };
  $.fn.optionTest.parseArray = function(vals, options) {
  var selectedOptions = options.holderObject.children("option:selected");
  console.log(selectedOptions.eq(0).html());
    $.each(vals, function(key, val) {
      $.fn.optionTest.parseContent(val, options,selectedOptions.eq(key).text());
    });
  };
  $.fn.optionTest.removeRow = function(elem, options) {
    var row = $(elem).parent().closest(options.rowOptions.tag);
    row.remove();
    $.fn.optionTest.updateRowIndex(options);
  };

$.fn.optionTest.updateRowIndex = function(options) {
    $("." + options.rowOptions.class).each(function(key,value) {
      var index = key+1;
      $(value).attr('rowdataid',index);
      $(value).children("."+options.indexOptions.class).html(index);
    });
  };

  $.fn.optionTest.createColumn = function(content) {
    var td = $('<td>');
    return td.append(content);
  }
  $.fn.optionTest.parseContent = function(val, options ,label) {

    var index = $('.' +    options.rowOptions.class).length+1;    


    var rowData = $.extend({}, options.rowOptions);
    var indexData = $.extend({}, options.indexOptions);

    rowData.rowDataId = index;    
    rowData.id = rowData.id + '-' + val;
    var fromData = $.extend({}, options.fromOptions);
    fromData.name = fromData.name + '-' + val;
    fromData.id = fromData.id + '-' + val;
    var toData = $.extend({}, options.toOptions);
    toData.name = toData.name + '-' + val;

    if ($('#' + rowData.id).length == 0) {
      var tag = "<" + rowData.tag + ">";
      delete rowData['tag'];
      var row = $(tag, rowData);      
      var id = $('<td>', indexData).html(index);  
      var label=$('<td>').html(label);
      var from = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", fromData));
      var to = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", toData));
      var removeRow = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<a>", options.removeLinkOptions).text('remove Row'));
      row.append(id).append(label).append(from).append(to).append(removeRow);

      $(options.actionId).append(row);
    }
  };
});
//Running The Plugin 
/**
Here is the Options
{
    clearOnChange:false  , 
  actionId:'#action',
    rowOptions:{
    id:'option', 
    class:'test-css'
  },
    fromOptions:{
    name:'from',
    type:'text', 
    value:'from', 
    size:20
  }, 
  toOptions:{
    name:'to',
    type:'text', 
    value:'to', 
    size:20  
  }
};
**/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').optionTest({
    actionId: '#action2',
    clearOnChange: false
  });
});
```

Here is the  options of plugin

```
 {
    clearOnChange: false,
    actionId: '#action',
    rowOptions: {
      id: 'option',
      class: 'test-css'
    },
    fromOptions: {
      name: 'from',
      type: 'text',
      value: 'from',
      size: 20
    },
    toOptions: {
      name: 'to',
      type: 'text',
      value: 'to',
      size: 20
    },
    removeLinkOptions: {
      class: 'removeRow',
      href: 'javascript:;'
    }
  }
```

You can edit change something .. clear the code ..   too many works on it .. but i hope you can add more options and functions   by yourself .. 
good luck

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a shot based on what you specified. This should give you a pretty good start. It works by showing certain divs within a form based on your selection. You can try it out here http://jsfiddle.net/v4gNL/530/

Here's the HTML

```
<body>
  <select id='options'>
    <option value="0">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">Option A</option>
    <option value="2">Option B</option>
    <option value="3">Option C</option>
    <option value="4">Option D</option>
  </select>
  <form action="">
    <div style='display:none;' id='optionA'>
      <br>1. Option A:&nbsp;
      <input type='text' class='text' name='optionAfrom' value="From" size='20' />
      <input type='text' class='text' name='optionAto' value="To" size='20' />
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div style='display:none;' id='optionB'>
      <br>2. Option B:&nbsp;
      <input type='text' class='text' name='optionBfrom' value="From" size='20' />
      <input type='text' class='text' name='optionBto' value="To" size='20' />
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div style='display:none;' id='optionC'>
      <br>3. Option C:&nbsp;
      <input type='text' class='text' name='optionCfrom' value="From" size='20' />
      <input type='text' class='text' name='optionCto' value="To" size='20' />
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div style='display:none;' id='optionD'>
      <br>4. Option D:&nbsp;
      <input type='text' class='text' name='optionDfrom' value="From" size='20' />
      <input type='text' class='text' name='optionDto' value="To" size='20' />
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div style='display:none;' id='submit'>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

And the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#options').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == '1') {
      $("#optionA").show();
    }
    if (this.value == '2') {
      $("#optionB").show();
    }
    if (this.value == '3') {
      $("#optionC").show();
    }
    if (this.value == '4') {
      $("#optionD").show();
    }
    if (this.value > '0') {
      $("#submit").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but It have static order. A always first, B always second and so on. I need something like: If I add B first I should get 1 row number and be in first row, after If I select A It should go with 2 rown number and add to  2nd row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id='options'>
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="A">Option A</option>
    <option value="B">Option B</option>
    <option value="C">Option C</option>
    <option value="D">Option D</option>
</select>

<table id="table" >
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>Date from</td>
    <td>Date to</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  var row = 1;
  $('#options').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val != '' )
  {
    var title = val;
    var tr = '<tr><td>'+row+'</td><td>Option'+title+'</td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>';
   $("#table").append(tr);
  row++;
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but there I can add duplicates, It should be ability to and only 1 row per value. Also how about removing row? Something like X button to remove row If selected wrong.

Answer (score -1):

how i add dropdown here

```
            szTr = szTr + "<td><input type='text' class='date_from'></td>"
            szTr = szTr + "<td><input type='text' class='date_to'></td>"
            szTr = szTr + "</tr>"
```

i want to add dropdown here without text field