# Display div when specific option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a DIV when a specific OPTION Value is selected. i have a html element like this.

```
 <select id="type">
  <option value="Article on Company">Article on Company</option>
  <option value="Article on Company">Article by Company</option>
  <option value="Concept Paper">Concept Paper</option>
</select>
```

And here is the following content

```
<div class="subdiv">
<div class="form-group mb-20">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="title">
</div>

<div class="form-group mb-20">
  <label>Description</label>
 <input class="form-control" name="description">
</div>
<div>
```

I want to hide the class subdiv when page load. If a user select the option "Article on Company" or "Article by Company"  i want to show input fields with name 'title, description'. If a user select the option with value "Concept Paper", then i want to show only input field with name description. Please help me.

Comment: Where is your javascript ? What have you tried, provide a minimum code

Comment: Please paste your effort & ask a doubt or problem you face. You can't ask the community to write the full code for you :)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Checkout this link (using JQuery): [Want to show/hide div based on dropdown box selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584752/want-to-show-hide-div-based-on-dropdown-box-selection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide/show element based on the selected option value. Try the following way:

```js
$('#type').change(function(){
  $('.subdiv').show();
  if($(this).val() == 'Article on Company' || $(this).val() == 'Article by Company'){
    $('[name=title], [name=description]').parent().show();
  }
  else if($(this).val() == 'Concept Paper'){
    $('[name=description]').parent().show();
    $('[name=title]').parent().hide();
  }
  else
    $('.subdiv').hide();
});
```

```css
.subdiv{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
  <option value="Select">---Select-</option>
  <option value="Article on Company">Article on Company</option>
  <option value="Article by Company">Article by Company</option>
  <option value="Concept Paper">Concept Paper</option>
</select>

<div class="subdiv">
<div class="form-group mb-20">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="title">
</div>

<div class="form-group mb-20">
  <label>Description</label>
 <input class="form-control" name="description">
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working.

Comment: @MahmoodMohammed, you are most welcome :)