# How to give the user two options to pick date (daily and monthly)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

I need to give the user the option to select a start and final date, which I'm using datepicker for, but also the option to select a start and final month, which then needs to be submitted as `DD/MM/YYYY`. I'm thinking about using a dropdown menu which changes between the datepicker and some other way of inputting the date, but the problem is that I suppose that any option the user chooses would need to be submitted under the same ID(?), which is used by the website to return data based on the time period selected. So far the website works with the datepicker, but that doesn't allow the user to select just a month. I made a snippet based on the first answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584752/want-to-show-hide-div-based-on-dropdown-box-selection/21584786) question just to illustrate what I was thinking. If the website uses the ID to show the data based on the time period submitted, how could it work with two options?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        $("#day").show();
        $("#month").hide();

      }
      else
      {
        $("#day").hide();
        $("#month").show();

      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='purpose'>
<option disabled selected value> -- escolha o tipo de dado -- </option>
<option value="0">Dado mensal</option>
<option value="1">Dado diário</option>
</select>

<div style='display:none;' id='day'>Dado diário<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='day' value size='20' />
    <br/>
</div>

<div style='display:none;' id='month'>Dado mensal<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='day' value size='20' />
    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want? Do you want a way to input just the month (1-12) or just the day (1-31) ?

Comment: I want to a) somehow "force" a `01/` before the date when the user chooses to get data by month (because the date needs to be formatted like that) and b) allow the website to accept the input, be it daily or monthly. Currently it accepts daily but it uses the ID to know what time period it returns data for, so I don't know how that would be done, since each element should have an unique ID.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is what you want, but I'm gonna post what I got and you can say your thoughts

Comment: Whenever i see someone using custom datepickers or weird date formats that isn't in the iso standard format it starts to crawl under my skin, why don't you use the correct input type="date or month" that is localized to the users choise? it have better accessibility and it is far more keyboard user friendly and works without javascript. whatever format i display localy it will always have the same date format when submitting the form and work super on touch devices

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what type of ID is that, there are a lot of configurations possible. It only depends on what you want. Check the difference between daily and monthly (from what I understood).

Ps: Try it with jQuery , here wont work

```js
const day = 18 // can be any
const excludeAllDaysExceptOne = date => (date.getDate() === day ? [true, ''] : [false, ''])

changeDaily = {
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
}

changeMonthly = {
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  beforeShowDay: excludeAllDaysExceptOne
}

$("#mySelect").change(() => {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', null);
  const x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
  if (x === 1) {
    setType(changeDaily)
  }
  if( x === 2 ){
    setType(changeMonthly)
  }
  $("#datepicker").removeAttr("disabled")
})

function setType(type){
 $(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker(type);
 })
}
```

```html
<p>Choose your input type
<select id="mySelect">
<option disabled selected>--Choose--</option>
<option>Daily</option>
<option>Monthly</option>
</select>
<br>
<p>Date: <input disabled type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: It returns `<a class='gotoLine' href='#65:22'>65:22</a> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`. I also got more information on my problem. The website uses getElementById to return data. My problem is what I thought it was, I need to offer two ways of selectind the date, but under a single ID so the website can work it out. Don't need to worry about the data formatting thing, it's already `dd/mm/yyyy` on the daily option, I think can work my way out to insert a random day when monthly is selected.

Comment: Oh, I could make it work out. My apologies for not being clear, the user should not have to select the day, just month and year, when he selects monthly.